# Exporting GGPlot to Powerpoint as a graph instead of an editable image

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, powerpoint

There are many excellent examples online of how to export GGPlot plots to Powerpoint (e.g. https://www.pipinghotdata.com/posts/2020-09-22-exporting-editable-ggplot-graphics-to-powerpoint-with-officer-and-purrr/).

However, in this example and others, plots are exported from R to Powerpoint as editable images instead of as graphs. This means that you can't check or edit the graph's data in the Powerpoint. Is it possible to export plots to Powerpoint as graphs, exporting not only the shapes and text of the plots but the data behind them too?

I am attaching an example of a GGPlot plot being exported to Powerpoint as an editable image instead of a graph. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvg)
library(purrr)
library(here)
library(officer)
datainter <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LucasTremlett/Proyecto-Visualizacion/master/owid-covid-data.csv")
dat.plot<- datainter %>% select(new_tests_per_thousand, new_cases_per_million, date, location) %>% drop_na(new_tests_per_thousand, new_cases_per_million) %>%
  group_by(location) %>% ungroup() %>% summarise(tot_tests_per1000=sum(new_tests_per_thousand),
                                   tot_cases_per_mil=sum(new_cases_per_million))

p<- dat.plot %>% 
  ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=tot_tests_per1000, y=tot_cases_per_mil), alpha=0.5, color="royalblue3") +
geom_smooth(aes(x=tot_tests_per1000, y=tot_cases_per_mil), method="loess", alpha=0.4, color="black") +
    geom_hline(yintercept=0) + geom_vline(xintercept=0) +
 scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10() +
  theme_minimal() + ylab("Casos totales por millón de habitantes") + xlab("Test totales por mil habitantes") +
  labs(title="¿El número de test aumenta el número de casos?",
       subtitle="Relación entre test y casos totales en varios países",
       caption="Fuente: Roser, M., Ritchie, H., Ortiz-Ospina, E. y Hasell, J. (2020)") +
    theme(text=element_text(family="serif"))

p_dml <- dml(ggobj = p)

read_pptx() %>%
  add_slide() %>%
  ph_with(p_dml, ph_location()) %>%
  print(
    target = here("plot.pptx"))
```

Comment: Pretty ambitious project! To see how a PowerPoint chart is composed, create one in a blank presentation. Save the file, change the ending to .zip, then look in the ppt/charts folder. You'll find 3 xml files chart1.xml with the chart data, colors1.xml holding the color series information and styles1.xml with the styling for each chart elements. Then consider that PowerPoint has 60 chart types, each requiring a different variant on a convertor algorithm.